# Search for minimum number of occurrences of a substring

Tags: api-testing, postman

The following is the Body of the response:

```
{
    "downloadTime": "2021:03:17T17:52:21Z",
    "downloadTimeStamp": 1616003541,
    "genome": "hg38",
    "chrom": "chrX",
    "start": 51657026,
    "end": 51658026,
    "dna": "tatgacgtaactatccatttatttagatcatcctcaaaaatatctcagtacaattttcagtgtatagattttgccaccttttgtgagatttatccctaagtatttcatgtttttaatgttatcatgctggtatttttatttaaatatcaaattgtttgttagtaatatatagaacggcaagtgatttttatagatatagcaagggggttttttgcagattctataggattattttatagagatgatcacatcttcatagacaaaagagacagttttacttaccgctttccaagtttttcttctgacccttttattaacattttttcttgtattattgcactagttagattaagcggtggacaacatatttgcccacttttttttcattttaagaggtaagtactcagtcttcatcactacatttcaagttacctgtaggtttttcatagatgccatttccttatcaagttgaggaagattgcttctgtttctagtttggtaagagttttaccaggaatgaatgctggatttgccaaatgatgtttctgcgtctattaaaatgactattttacaaatctgttaatattgtgaattacattgatttgtttttctaaggttaaactacctttgcattctttggtcatgatgcattatccttttccccaggtaatactggcttcgtacaatgagtcaggaaatattccatttctttaattttctggaaaaaaaattctgtgggtggcattatttcttccttatatgattagtagaatccacaagtaaatccatctgggcctttaattttctttgtggaaggttttaaagtagaagcttaatgtattgaagagtgttttaatcacctcctatttatcccattagtgagggagggattcctgcctaggtttaggcaaatggctggcgtatgacacgacaccggacacatgagactgttagcaatttattagtaatgtatactcacaacctgagagaggaggatacc"
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1- I need to check if the “dna” contains at least 10 “Ngg” sites. That means if there are a minimum of 10 [acgt]gg sites (agg or cgg or tgg or ggg). How do I write a test for that?

2- Is the following test for validating schema correct?

```
const schema = {
  "downloadTime": "data-time",
  "genome": "{{human genome}}",  //human genome is a collection level variable
  "chrom": ("chrX"|"chrY"),
};
pm.test('Schema is valid', function() {
  pm.response.to.have.jsonSchema(schema);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to check if the “dna” contains at least 10 “Ngg” sites. That means if there are a minimum of 10 [acgt]gg sites (agg or cgg or tgg or ggg). How do I write a test for that?

You need to first find all such occurences:

```javascript
resultArray = [...dna.matchAll(/[acgt]gg/g)]
```

then you need to assert the length:

```javascript
pm.test('Number of occurences if equal or greater than 10', function() {
    pm.expect(resultArray.length).to.be.above(9);
});
```

All put together, it could look like so:

```javascript
const jsonData = pm.response.json();

pm.test('Number of occurences is equal or greater than 10', function() {
    const dna = jsonData.dna;
    resultArray = [...dna.matchAll(/[acgt]gg/g)];
    pm.expect(resultArray.length).to.be.above(9);
});
```

> Is the following test for validating schema correct?

Most certainly not. If I copy & paste it and use it as a test for a completely different response, the test passes. You, for example, don't specify any required properties as shown for example [here](https://postman-quick-reference-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/schema-validation.html).

Comment: Thank you SO much for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 2):

> I need to check if the “dna” contains at least 10 “Ngg” sites. That
> means if there are a minimum of 10 [acgt]gg sites (agg or cgg or tgg
> or ggg). How do I write a test for that?

```
pm.test('length validation', function () {
    pm.expect((pm.response.json().dna.match(/[acgt]gg/g) || []).length).to.be.greaterThan(10)
});
```

> Is the following test for validating schema correct?

**No:**

**Correct usage:**

The supported json types are:
https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/index.html

> ```
> Numeric types
> object
> array
> boolean
> null
> ```

**JSON schema is used to validate whether the required properties are present and is of the mentioned data type.**

eg

```
const schema = {
  
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        
        "code": { "type": "string" }
    },
    "required":["code"]

}

pm.test('Schema is valid', function () {
    console.log(pm.response.json())
    pm.response.to.have.jsonSchema(schema);
});
```

Here it checks the response is an object meaning its inside {} , and has a required property called "code" and is string.

**In your case you have to do value validation also**

```
pm.response.json.downloadTime === //somevalidation for date-time
```

Comment: Thanks SO much for your thorough answer and for taking the time to help!

Comment: Please accept the answer that helped by clicking the tick sign